# Angular headers.get(...) is null

Tags: angular

I'm building an angular 14 application with a backend using spring cloud gateway. I have configured CORS in the gateway. I run the application on http://localhost:4200.
The first call to the backend is to get user information. I defined a method :

```
getUserInfo() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8180/auth/userInfo", {}, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // store user details in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
}
```

And I have 2 Interceptors : 1 for setting the X-Requested-With header and 1 for intercepting errors :

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
    
        if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
            
            const error = err.error.message;
            return throwError(error);
         } else {
             console.error(`Error type ${err.name}`);
             console.error(err.message);
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            if (err.status === 401) {
                console.warn(`Backend returned code 401, login out`);
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            } else {
                console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}`);
                if (err.error) {
                    console.error(`app error code was: ${err.error.code}`);
                }
            }
              
            return throwError(err);
          }
    }))
}
```

The problem I get is the call to getUserInfo() always return a TypeError error with the message "headers.get(...) is null"

I can't see any request made to the backend neither in my browser log or in the backend access log.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

**EDIT**

The call to the getUserInfo() is in a component :

```
ngOnInit() {
    //this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.getUserInfo()
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            },
            error => {
                this.errorMsg = error.message;
            });
}
```

Comment: Did you subscribed to this `getUserInfo()` ?

Comment: I updated my post with how I call getUserInfo()

Answer (score 0):

- Verify that you Import HttpHeaders from @angular/common/http.
- Try to use the tap to console the data before the map
- In your components verify that you subscribe to getserInfo function.

In the Service try to use that in the ctor

```
constructor(){
this.header=new HttpHeaders();
this.header=this.header.append('ContentType','application/json');
this.header=this.header.append('Accept','application/json')
}
```

and call it

```
//code...
  return this.http.post(url,{},{headers:this.header});
```

Comment: "Verify that you Import HttpHeaders from @angular/common/http" - project will compile otherwise?

Comment: - HttpHeaders is imported in app.module.ts
 - I will try the tap
 - I think that the subscribe is made, see my updated post

Comment: Try to use the append with the headers .I edit the code , @robert : just to verify that it was the good path import

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was due to an another interceptor that I put to work with a mock configuration and that was causing the error.